# How to get the LatLng of a "dragend" event in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to get the lat and long of a dragged and dropped marker on the Leaflet map.

However, I'm constantly getting `TypeError: event.latlng is undefined` error.

This is my entire code:

```
var map = L.map('map');

googleStreets = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
  maxZoom: 20,
  subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
}).addTo(map);

map.locate({
  setView: true, 
  maxZoom: 16, 
  watch:false, 
  timeout: 60000,
  enableHighAccuracy: true
});
var marker; 
var circles;

function onLocationFound(e) {
  var radius = e.accuracy / 2;

  if(map.hasLayer(circles) && map.hasLayer(marker)) {
    map.removeLayer(circles);
    map.removeLayer(marker);
  } 

  marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng, {draggable:true});
  circles = new L.circle(e.latlng, radius);
  circles.bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();;

  map.addLayer(marker);
  map.addLayer(circles);

  marker.on('dragend', function(event) {
    var mylat = event.latlng.lat
    var result = marker.getLatLng(); 
    console.log(mylat);
  });
}
```

when I see inside the console, I see that error.

But when i change this `console.log(mylat);` to this `console.log(result);`, I see the lat and long in the console but the format of them is not what I am looking for.

This is what I get in the console when i drag and drop the marker the code with this  `console.log(result);`:

```
 Object { lat=51.564025924107554,  lng=0.7077598571777344,  equals=function(),  more...}
```

Could someone please advise on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're listening to a `L.Marker`'s `dragend` event. If you look at the [documentation for that](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#marker-dragend), you'll see that `dragend` events fire event handlers which receive a [`DragEndEvent`, which only has `distance`, `type` and `target` properties](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#dragendevent). No `latlng`. That's expected.

Now, the `target` property of a `DragEndEvent` is the `L.Marker` instance. So:

- You do **not** want the `LatLng` of the `DragEndEvent`, because it doesn't even exist
- You want the `LatLng` of the `L.Marker` which is the `target` of the `DragEndEvent`.

And how do you get the `LatLng` of a `L.Marker`? With its `getLatLng()` method. So:

```
marker.on('dragend', function(event) {
  var latlng = event.target.getLatLng();
  console.log(latlng.lat, latlng.lng)
});
```

See a [working example](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/xub/edit?html,console,output).